# Background thread vs Async thread pool

Tags: greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I see from the GreenRobot EventBus [documentation](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/delivery-threads-threadmode/) that with thread mode `BACKGROUND` a single background thread is used and with thread mode `ASYNC` a thread pool is used.

Anyone happen to know whether the background thread used by the `BACKGROUND` thread mode separate and distinct from the threads used by the `ASYNC` thread mode?

I ask because I want to use `BACKGROUND` thread mode for quick events (like local file access) and I want to use `ASYNC` thread mode for slow(er) events (like network calls)... and naturally I'd like it if `BACKGROUND` events were never waiting on `ASYNC` events to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from the GreenRobot Team [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/391) as follows:

> Each has its own queue ([AsyncPoster](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/V3.0.0/EventBus/src/org/greenrobot/eventbus/AsyncPoster.java), [BackgroundPoster](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/V3.0.0/EventBus/src/org/greenrobot/eventbus/BackgroundPoster.java)) and both use
>   the same cached thread pool [ExecutorService](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/V3.0.0/EventBus/src/org/greenrobot/eventbus/EventBusBuilder.java#L30). So yes, they should not
>   block each other.
>
> However, if you always use `ASYNC` those will also not block each other
>   as each will use its own thread (the docs even warn about [too many
>   concurrent threads](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/V3.0.0/EventBus/src/org/greenrobot/eventbus/ThreadMode.java#L53)).